# CollectionView inside a Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, collectionview

[image: Home View Controller]

I want to Include one text label with large text (around 10-15 lines) and two collection views in a table view. This is my home view controller on login.Also other button and title label are as shown in image. Both collection views are horizontally scrollable and table view containing all these is vertically scrollable.Further each collection view cell has some data with fields that are populated at runtime from web service calls. As shown in image attached. Requirements - **Xcode 6**, **should be using storyboard** (no xib, no coding only), **objective c** only, **iPad only**.

Comment: I don't remember adding an image needs certain reputation.. are you sure?

Comment: @Sagar need 15 reputation to post image :)

Comment: 15 no problem....Where is image? Tejas?

Comment: @JoeHallenbeck - I am unable to post the image. Since it has minimum of 15 reputation requirements.

Comment: @JoeHallenbeck Image added

Comment: @Tejas hey, i delete my unswer, in your question you should write what help you want? and it isn't enough pictures, it is desirable to add a code, if it's possible?

Comment: So, what's the issue?

Comment: @JoeHallenbeck  Issue is everything works fine in portrait mode, but when I rotate to landscape mode the 2nd collection view gets hidden since the screen size is not adequate. So, what I did is added a scroll view and then placed all these things on top of it. Still the scroll view doesn't work.

Comment: @BhanuPriya See my above comment for the issue. orientation of content doesn't change on change of screen orientation

Comment: Make sure that content size larger than the scrollview's frame

Comment: @BhanuPriya : Thanks for the suggestions. Yes the issue was with the AutoLayout and improper constraints.

Comment: @JoeHallenbeck : Thanks for the guidance and suggestions. issue is resolved now.